# registration form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just a beginner ,and i was trying to create a form registration using JavaScript.

Its about choosing a book from a library. In this all inputs are mandatory ,and it includes first `name`, `lastname`, `gender` ,`email`,`password`and a list of books that should be chosen and also the date that is chosen. After validating using JavaScript, display proper error message in text box where there is an error.

It is not displaying the submit button,if I delete the list with books and the date it appears ,but in other cases no.

This is the full code :

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 }
body
{
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-image: url("11.jpg");
 }
#container{
 width:550px;
 background-color:rgba(250,250,252,.9);
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 box-shadow:0 0 3px #999;
 opacity:0.4;
 }
#container_body
{
 padding:20px;
 }
.form_title
{
 font-size:35px;
 color:#141823;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
 font-weight:normal;
 }
.head_para{
 font-size:19px;
 color:#99a2a7;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:normal;
 }
#form_emri{
 padding:25px 0 0 15px;
 }
.emrimbiemri
{
  margin-right:20px;
 }
.input_name{
 width:207px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
#email_form{
 clear:both;
 padding:15px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_email{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
#Re_email_form
{
 padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_Re_email
{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
#password_form 
{
 padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_password
{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
.birthday_title
{
 font-size:16px; 
 color:#8b919d; 
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:0 0 10px 0;
 }
.libri_title
 {
  font-size:16px; 
 color:#8b919d; 
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:0 0 10px 0;
 }
.d_marrjes
{
font-size:16px; 
 color:#8b919d; 
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:0 0 10px 0;
 }
select
{
 padding:5px;
 }
#birthday
{
 font-size:12px;
 color:#8b919d;
 padding-top:10px;
 }
#radio_button
{
 padding:10px 0 0 0;
 }
#sign_user
{
 font-size:14px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#3B5998;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
#errorBox
{
 color:#F00;
 }
</style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function Submit()
  {
         var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
            var fname = document.form.Name.value,
                lname = document.form.LastName.value,
                  femail = document.form.Email.value,
                   freemail = document.form.enterEmail.value,
                    fpassword = document.form.Password.value,
                      fmonth = document.form.birthday_month.value,
                        fday = document.form.birthday_day.value,
                           fyear = document.form.birthday_year.value;
                             flibri=document.form.libri.value;
                               datMarrje=document.form.d_marrjes.value;
   
      if( fname == "" )
      {
            document.form.Name.focus() ;
              document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Fusni emrin ";
              return false;
        }
     if( lname == "" )
     {
          document.form.LastName.focus() ;
           document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Fusni mbiemrin";
             return false;
        }
    
     if (femail == "" )
       {
         document.form.Email.focus();
             document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Fusni  email";
              return false;
       }
    else if(!emailRegex.test(femail))
    {
          document.form.Email.focus();
            document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Fusni  email e validimit";
             return false;
        }
   
     if (freemail == "" )
       {
          document.form.enterEmail.focus();
             document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Fusni serish email";
               return false;
        }
  else if(!emailRegex.test(freemail))
  {
              document.form.enterEmail.focus();
                 document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Fusni serish  email e validimit";
                  return false;
        }
   
      if(freemail !=  femail)
     {
              document.form.enterEmail.focus();
                  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Email-et nuk perputhen, futini serish";
                    return false;
         }
   
   
      if(fpassword == "")
          {
             document.form.Password.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Fusni password";
                  return false;
          }
   
      if (fmonth == "") 
      {
             document.form.birthday_month.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Zgjidhni muajin e lindjes";
                 return false;
         }
       if (fday == "")
         {
                document.form.birthday_day.focus();
                  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Zgjidhni diten e lindjes";
                    return false;
            }
       if (fyear == "")
         {
             document.form.birthday_year.focus();
                 document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Zgjidhni vitin e lindjes";
                  return false;
           }
         if(document.form.radiobutton[0].checked == false && document.form.radiobutton[1].checked == false)
     {
             document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Zgjidhni gjinine";
               return false;
           }
        if (flibri == "") 
     {
              document.form.libri.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "selecto librin";
                 return false;
            }
         if (datMarrje == "")
      {
              document.form.d_marrje.focus();
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "selecto daten";
                  return false;
            }
          if(fname != '' && lname != '' && femail != '' && freemail != '' && fpassword != '' && fmonth != '' && fday != '' && fyear != ''&& flibri!='' && datMarrje!='')
     {
             document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Forma u krye me sukses ";
            }
     
    }
</script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="emptyDiv"></div>
      <div id="description"></div>
        <!--container fillon-->
          <div id="container">
             <div id="container_body">
                <!--Form fillon-->
                   <div id="form_emri">
                      <div class="emrimbiemri">
                         <form name="form" >
                            <div id="errorBox"></div>
                               <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="Emri"  class="input_name" >
                                   <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" placeholder="Mbiemri" class="input_name" >
         
                        </div>
            <div id="email_form">
                <input type="text" name="Email" value=""  placeholder=" Email" class="input_email">
            </div>
               <div id="Re_email_form">
                 <input type="text" name="enterEmail" value=""  placeholder="Rifut Email" class="input_Re_email">
            </div>
                 <div id="password_form">
                   <input type="password" name="Password" value=""  placeholder=" Password" class="input_password">
            </div>
                   <!--te dhenat e ditelindjes fillojne ketu-->
                <div>
                  <h3 class="birthday_title">Ditelindje</h3>
                 </div>
                      <div>
                             <select name="birthday_month" >
                               <option value="" selected >Muaji</option>
                                 <option value="1">Jan</option>
                                  <option value="2">Feb</option>
                                    <option value="3">Mar</option>
                                      <option value="4">Apr</option>
                                         <option value="5">May</option>
                                            </select>
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                  <select name="birthday_day" >
                                                   <option value="" selected>Data</option>
                                                      <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                         <option value="3">3</option>
                                                             <option value="4">4</option>
                                                                <option value="5">5</option>
                            </select>
                                                               <select name="birthday_year">
                                                                   <option value="" selected>Viti</option>
                                                                     <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                                                        <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                                                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                                                                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                                                                  <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                                               </select>
                        </div>
               <!--te dhenat e ditelindjes perfundojne ketu-->
                    <div id="radio_button">
                           <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Femer">
                             <label >Femer</label>
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Mashkull">
                                      <label >Mashkull</label>
                     </div>  
      <div>
                    <p id="sign_user" onClick="Submit()">Sign Up </p>
                 </div>

            <div>
              <h3 class="libri_title">Zgjidhni librin</h3>
                <select name="libri">
                   <option value="Keshtjella">Keshtjella-<b>Ismail Kadare</b></option>
                        <option value="Charls Dikens">A Tale of Two Cities-<b>Charls Dikens</b></option>
                           <option value="Cao Xueqin">The Dream Of The red Chamber-<b>Cao Xueqin</b></option>
                             <option value="Rowling">Harry Poter-<b>Rowling</b></option>
                </select>
            </div>
         <div>
             <h3 class="d_marrjes">Data e marrjes: </h3><br/>
               <input type="date"name="date",id="demo"/>
                   <script>
                        var d = new Date();
                             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toString();
                    <script>
      </div>

      </form>     
 
   </div>
       <!--Forma mbaroi-->
  </div>
</div>
     <!--container mbaroi-->
</body
</html>
```

Comment: Do you expect us to read all that code? Extract few important lines which are not working.

Comment: when i'm finished reading all those lines, i will probably have a beard like santa claus

Comment: The code here is necessary to run the snippet and reproduce the issue. I'm not sure that s/he should leave out any part of it here. @Fatjona you can however reduce the snippet to the isolated piece that is buggy and link to a jsfiddle with the full implementation of the page.

Comment: lol if i were you i would look at creating a new registration page. There are multiple tutorials out there with much more efficient code.

Comment: there's so many errors on the html structure... a good point to start is working on a better and more solid html structure

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors here:

First, your `input` with `id='demo'` is incorrect. Attributes (like type, name, and id) should not have commas in between them. Your input tag should appear like this:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="demo"/>
```

Second, this line is wrong:

```
datMarrje = document.form.d_marrjes.value;
```

It assumes that your `<form name="form">` has a child `<input name="d_marrjes"`but it doesn't. You should replace it with

```
datMarrje = document.form.date.value;
```

After fixing these errors, it worked for me.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer to my question ,but if the submit button appears ,it doesnt include the dropdown list box to choose the book and also the day to be choosen .Both ,appears on form registration but not above  the submit button .

Comment: when i complete all the form ,it appears the message the the form was completes successfully,but the submit button should be under the list of books and date that is chosen ,and should appear a message that says choose book,date .